# Cannot convert value of type 'visibleLessonStruct' to expected argument type 'Binding<visibleLessonStruct?>

Tags: swiftui

I am updating the state 'lessonVisible' in my parent view "LessonOverview" from my child component "LessonView"

The code its self if working as expected and the state is updated in the parent. However the code will not work with the preview.

I am getting the error below on line 45 in the preview provider struct:

> Cannot convert value of type 'visibleLessonStruct' to expected
>   argument type 'Binding'

on the line:

> LessonView(lessonVisible: visibleLessonStruct(lessonType:
>   .Reading)).previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: "iPhone XS"))

How do I resolve this issue?

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct visibleLessonStruct{
    var lessonType: LessonType
}

enum LessonType{
    case Reading, Listening, Practice
}

struct LessonView: View {

     @Binding var lessonVisible : visibleLessonStruct!

    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { geometry in
        VStack{

            HStack{
                Spacer()

                Button(action: {
                    print("Close button tapped!")
                    self.lessonVisible = nil
                }) {
                    Image("cross").renderingMode(.original).resizable().frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                }

            }.padding(10).padding(.trailing, 10)
            Spacer()
        }.background(Color.white).statusBar(hidden: true)
    }
    }
}


struct LessonView_Previews: PreviewProvider {



    static var previews: some View {

        LessonView(lessonVisible: visibleLessonStruct(lessonType: .Reading)).previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: "iPhone XS"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try wrapping it inside a `.constant` like this:

```swift
struct LessonView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
    LessonView(lessonVisible: .constant(visibleLessonStruct(lessonType: .Reading))).previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: "iPhone XS"))
    }
}
```

constants ares used in previews to mimic the behavior of Bindable and State variables.